# Offset in VBA by 1 moves 6 to the right, but offset by -1 moves 1 to the left

Tags: vba, excel

So I am using several counters to go through my sheet and check values to the left and right of a cell. When this message box is shown, it shows:

Right cell column: 14

Current cell column: 8

Left cell column: 7

In other words, the left cell is 1 column to the left, like it should be. But the right cell is 6 columns to the right! I just used a 1 for the column shift, and tried doing it using a variable name, subtraction, and with the columnOffset:= prefix. I googled about how the Offset function is used, but found nothing related to a problem like this one.

Here is my code:

```
MsgBox "Right cell column: " & ActiveSheet.Cells(2, currCount2 - 1).Offset(treeCount - 1, 1).Column & vbNewLine & "Current cell column: " & ActiveSheet.Cells(2, currCount2 - 1).Offset(treeCount - 1, 0).Column & vbNewLine & "Left Cell column: " & ActiveSheet.Cells(2, currCount2 - 1).Offset(treeCount - 1, -1).Column
```

Comment: Merged cells by any chance?

Comment: @Rory: I was thinking the same thing you beat me to it

Comment: It happens whether the cells are merged or not

Comment: Actually, one of my counters is not moving like I thought, so nvm. What would be the solution if the cells are merged?

Comment: @Rory do you know?

Comment: If your active cell is F1 and you have C1:E1 merged, and you want to get the value of B1, you would offset it by 4..`MsgBox Range("F1").Offset(0, -4).Value` or `MsgBox ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Value`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am posting an answer to this because someone searching for this might want to find a solution. The problem is merged cells. Before you run code like this, check for merged cells, like for my case, it would be:

```
If ActiveSheet.Cells(2, currCount2 - 1).Offset(treeCount - 1, 1).MergeCells Then
```

And then you want to find the first value in the MergeArea instead:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, currCount2 - 1).Offset(treeCount - 1, 1).MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Value
```

Hope this helps someone out there! :)